# Visual studios not respecting the environment variable from windows batch file

Tags: c++, macros, visual-studio-2019, preprocessor-directive

I have a C++ project in visual studios 2019. I want to achieve conditional compilation. For this is defined a version in windows .bat (launch_solution.bat) file and launch the visual studios project from the same bat file.  I read the value of this variable in the macro and then try to do conditional compilation. It seems to work for the first time when I launch .bat file. But when I close the visual studio, change the value of the variable and then launch the bat file again, it does not work.

This is what my launch_solution.bat looks like.

set /A CODE_VER=1 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "C:\Users\dnaik\Work_Projects\Macros_Built\Macros_Built.vcxproj"

In visual studios, under C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions, I have defined a macro: VER=$(CODE_VER)

I change the CODE_VER value in the bat file and execute the batch file to launch visual studios and then  do compilation for different versions of the code.

```
// This is the header file 
#ifndef _COMMONUTILITY_H_
#define _COMMONUTILITY_H_

#if VER==1
#define ADDITION
#elif VER==2
#define MULTIPLICATION
#else
#define SUBTRACT
#endif

#endif



// This is the src file
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "CommonUtility.h"

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> zVec = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

#ifdef  ADDITION
    int iResult = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < zVec.size(); i++)
    {
        iResult += zVec[i];
    }
    std::cout << iResult << std::endl;

#endif //  ADDITION


#ifdef MULTIPLICATION
    long iMultResult = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < zVec.size(); i++)
    {
        iMultResult *= zVec[i];
    }

    std::cout << iMultResult << std::endl;

#endif // MULTIPLICATION


#ifdef SUBTRACT
    int iSubtractResult = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < zVec.size(); i++)
    {
        iSubtractResult -= zVec[i];
    }
    std::cout << iSubtractResult << std::endl;

#endif // SUBTRACT

    return 0;
}
```

When I launch the visual studios from batch file for the first time, the conditional compilation works as expected. But When I change the CODE_VER value and launch visual studio again, the VER value does not change.

Comment: My guess would be, the build system doesn't realize that the project needs to be rebuilt, and runs previously built executable. You can explicitly rebuilt it via `Build > Rebuild` menu (citing from memory).

Comment: I tried rebuilt. It does not work. VER value in the header is still 1. When I check the evaluated value of VER in the visual studios windows of preprocessor (VER=$(CODE_VER) ) it is 2.

Comment: When I do Project->Rescan Solution, then VER is set to correct value.  I'll check if there some automated view to do this

Comment: Rather than playing with environment variables, why not create additional project configurations, and set VER macro to a constant value, different in each one? This way, you can easily control from the IDE which configuration(s) are being built.